# Getting weird indentation errors in python anywhere

Tags: python, python-2.7, indentation, pythonanywhere

Im am using pythonanywhere to run my python code, and i recently got weird indentation error from nowhere. This is how it looks:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/ho26q4gpzd0qvpj/Screen%20Shot%202015-04-05%20at%2014.17.18.png?dl=0

What to do?

Comment: You are mixing tabs and spaces; use your editor to convert tabs to spaces instead. Then configure that same editor to insert spaces every time you use the TAB key to indent.

Comment: Ok i will try that thank you, But why do i get -1?

Comment: I don't know as I cannot know why other people vote. I *think* they may have voted because your question shows no research effort and you didn't include your code; linking to a screenshot externally is generally frowned upon.

Comment: Normally i would write the code here but as this is an indentation error i wanted you people to see exactly as i see there which would increase the odds of finding the fault maybe. I have solved these kinds of problems when its in my own text editor but as this was in python anywhere i did not know how to fix it there. People are way to harsh here i think. Anyways thank you

Comment: PythonAnywhere isn't really a factor here; their Python implementation is not materially different in this respect. You could have confirmed this by running Python locally on the file, for example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replace all spaces with tabs or vice-versa. Make sure you are consistent!

Answer (score 2):

to develops in python use a text editor that prints special character (tab, space, new line) so you can see where you have a space instead of tab for  indentation!
hope helped you!